# Writing an isnull() wrapper for nvl()

Tags: oracle, plsql

We are moving our database from Oracle to SQL Server. My queries make extensive use of Oracle's nvl function. In SQL Server, the function to use is isnull(). If possible, I'd like to start getting my queries ready by changing them to use isnull(), while still on Oracle. My idea is to create a wrapper function isnull() in my schema and change my queries to use that function instead. That way when we switch database platforms, my queries are already using the new function.

Is there a way I can create a wrapper function in Oracle called isnull() that accepts and returns any datatype? Or do I just have to have multiple isnull() declarations, overloaded for all the expected data types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another approach might be to use `COALESCE` instead of `NVL`, since the syntax for `COALESCE` is the same in both Oracle and SQL Server.  Still, the goal (if it is your goal) of having identical SQL that works efficiently (or even works at all) in both Oracle and SQL Server may not be realistic.

Answer (score 1):

The only way in PL/SQL to have multiple overloads for the same function would be to create them in a package.  You can create a package that includes a number of different overloaded `IsNull` functions that accept and return different data types and use those in your queries.  Of course, that does mean that you will have to include the package name in your code.  It's potentially easy enough to remove the package name when you move to SQL Server but it won't be an exact migration.